# .htaccess RewriteRule not retaining capture group during domain redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have an HTTPS subdomain, https://donate.example.com/, which points to the same web root as the www domain. I have a script on my server in the folder /donate/, and inside of there I have an .htaccess file which has the following code. I want to make sure any requests to http://www.example.com/donation/ (or http://direct.example.com/donation/) will redirect to https://donate.example.com/donation/.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^donate\.example\.com$ [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://donate.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The issue I'm having is that the capture-group in RewriteRule (`^(.*)$`) is not being copied into the destination URL (`$1`), so the user is only being redirected to the webroot instead of the full path. This means that the user is being redirected to https://donate.example.com/ instead of https://donate.example.com/donation/ (which is the behavior I need/expect).

Any idea why the capture-group isn't working?

Comment: Could it be that you are facing a caching issue? Please make a deep reload or clear your browser cache...

Comment: I'm testing it using curl on the command prompt: `curl --head http://www.example.com/donation/`. The result is always `Location: https://donation.example.com/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that inside `/donation/` folder captured value for `http://www.example.com/donation/` will be empty since it is relative to `/donation/`.

Try this code instead:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /donation/

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^donate\.example\.com$ [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
 RewriteRule ^ https://donate.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```